# What is the best way to have full text search where data in database is frequently updated

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am working on an application where the database is continuously and periodically updated, and the frequency of updating of data is daily, weekly, monthly, and yearly based on their type. I want to implement full text search, I am using MySQL and applied full text indexes, and the search is working fine, but the job working for addition/updating of data was adversely impacted.

Does anyone have a solution that can be implemented for full text search for a continuously updated dataset?

Comment: @Nitin Are you open to use other techs as `elasticsearch` or `sphinx`? When write scalability problems hit, it'll be harder for you to scale your MySQL. Unless you strictly need to have [_transactional FULL TEXT SEARCH_](http://www.3manuek.com/fts-innodb), I'll suggest you to rethink the topology.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that update frequency in the worst case, would be a day, in your case. You could try Sphinx for this, as it is really fast and works well with MySql. And you could think of ElasticSearch also if the data is huge.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271600/elasticsearch-sphinx-lucene-solr-xapian-which-fits-for-which-usage

Answer (score 0):

A good way to update FT indexes, if they are somewhat big is to.

```
1. Drop the FT index
2. Update the data
3. Add new FT index.
```

I had major problems updating tables with FT indedxes when they grew big, this solution worked for me. I have now however moved all FT indexing to a Lucene solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating by replacing the data, then this has 'zero' downtime.

1. `CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;`
2. Load the new data into `new`.  The new FT index will be built.
3. `RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;  -- fast and atomic; hence zero downtime.
4. `DROP TABLE old;`

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to use other techs as elasticsearch or sphinx? When write scalability problems hit, it'll be harder for you to scale your MySQL. Unless you strictly need to have transactional FULL TEXT SEARCH, I'll suggest you to rethink the topology.

Otherwise, you can DROP the FTS index, bulk load the data and recreate it.
More details in [Considerations and recommendations](http://www.3manuek.com/fts-innodb).

Also, even if you recreate index you need to consider the [alter online limitations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html) for this particular situation:

```
Creating the first FULLTEXT index for a table involves a table copy, 
unless there is a user-supplied FTS_DOC_ID column. Subsequent FULLTEXT indexes
on the same table can be created in-place.
```

The problem is that you will need to use `myloader` as a [this bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80347) doesn't allow to restore a backup from mysqldump when defining `FTS_DOC_ID` columns.

Meaning that, if you want to do the drop/alter in place, you will need to define your own `FTS_DOC_ID` column.

NOTE: A better version of the original article is [here](https://www.pythian.com/blog/mysql-innodbs-full-text-search-overview/).